# Compress output of Hadoop Archive tool

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-archive, bigdata

I'm using [Hadoop Archive](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html) for reduce number of files in my Hadoop cluster, but for data retention, I want to keep my data as long as possible. Then the problem is Hadoop Archive not reduce folder size (my folder have multi-type of file, both small and large file, then not suitable for use Sequence File).

I used some option like `-D mapreduce.compress.map.output=true -D mapred.map.ouput.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec` but it's not work.

Does anyone know a way for compress output of Hadoop Archive, or suggest me someway to get both goal (compress size and reduce number of file).

Any infomation is appreciate. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may use mapred compress and run har on the compressed directories

Comment: Can you give more details? When use another map-reduce job before run har can destroy the original directories structures.